Cloud function deploys successfully but does now show up under Firebase- Functions, why is this?
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const axios = require("axios");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp();
const storage = admin.storage();

// Specify the region for your functions
exports.generateImage = functions.region('asia-east1').https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { prompt } = req.body;

        if (!prompt) {
            return res.status(400).send({ error: "Prompt is required" });
        }

        // Hugging Face API Configuration
        const apiUrl = "https://api-inference.huggingface.co/models/stabilityai/stable-diffusion-2-1";
        const apiToken = "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"; // Replace with your Hugging Face API token

        // Call Hugging Face API
        const response = await axios.post(
            apiUrl,
            { inputs: prompt },
            {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${apiToken}`,
                },
                responseType: "arraybuffer", // To get binary image data
            }
        );

        // Upload Image to Firebase Storage
        const bucket = storage.bucket();
        const fileName = `images/${Date.now()}.png`;
        const file = bucket.file(fileName);

        await file.save(response.data, {
            metadata: {
                contentType: "image/png",
            },
        });

        const fileUrl = `https://storage.googleapis.com/${bucket.name}/${fileName}`;

        // Return the Image URL
        return res.status(200).send({ imageUrl: fileUrl });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return res.status(500).send({ error: "Failed to generate image" });
    }
});

My project ID is correct. My package.json is also correct. All dependencies are installed. I am not sure why it is not showing up on firebase... I tried deploying so many times. And it always deploys successfully. I tried re-initilaizing firebase. My region is also correct.
